# which method will be called during the selection the perticular row from table view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Table view contain 7 rows in which I have to select 1 row then control transfer to the other `xib` file with some global data.

How is it possible?

Comment: Exactly, what you want right now?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method will be called on click of one of the row in tableview.

**EDIT** : You can display alert like this inside this method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                      message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is your UIAlertview message with row number %d.",indexPath.row];                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    [message release];
}
```

Comment: ex: i have to show window alert view  whenever i  clicked in that row...

Comment: Please look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *mealArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {   
      mealArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Breakfast",@"Lunch",@"Dinner",@"Others", nil];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     cell.textLabel.text = [mealArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     newViewController *newVC = [[newViewController alloc] init];
     newVC.mealType = [mealArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: laxonline: here newViewController mean??

Comment: Push next viewcontroller with the meal type.

Comment: what you suppose to say??

Comment: Exactly, what you want right now?